# How to filter database records based on more than one condition using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I started learning SQL with Java, and I am trying to make Register/Login System using `Swing` and `SQLite`.

So, I made almost whole basic login system, but I am stuck. I have table called `user`s, and I have 2 text fields with button, and if button is clicked it just says hello + 'username'. So in my table, for example, I have 2 values:

For example, I have table 'user':

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| admin    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

with data:

```
+----------+-------------+
| admin    | password    |
+----------+-------------+
| myLogin  | myPassword  |
| myLogin1 | myPassword1 |
+----------+-------------+
```

It will just recognise when I enter myUsername1 , myPassword1 etc. It wont recognise if I enter myUsername, myPassword

So basically I am trying to figure out how to check if user entered for example just
   admin password
and than say hello admin etc.

So here is my Connect.java

```
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Connect {

static String username;
static String password;
static String query;

public static Connection ConnectDB() {
    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Alex\\workspace   \\RegisterAndLoginSystem\\System.sqlite");

        Statement state = null;
        state = conn.createStatement();

        query = "SELECT * FROM `user`";
        // This query does not work as well
        // query = "SELECT admin,password FROM user WHERE admin = '" + GuiLogin.user + "' AND password = '" + GuiLogin.pass + "'";


        ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
            username = rs.getString("admin");
            System.out.println(username);
            password = rs.getString("password");
            System.out.println(password);
        }
        rs.close();
        state.close();

        return conn;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not connect: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

For example now I can just enter admin1 password1 and just than it will validate but I have too admin password which I can not validate.

Here is my GUI Class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class GuiLogin extends JFrame {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField field1;
    private JPasswordField field2;
    private JLabel label1, label2, answer;

    static String user;
    static String pass;

    public GuiLogin() {

        try {
             UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        panel = new JPanel();

        label1 = new JLabel("Username:");
        panel.add(label1);

        field1 = new JTextField("", 15);
        panel.add(field1);

        label2 = new JLabel("Password:");
        panel.add(label2);

        field2 = new JPasswordField("", 15);
        panel.add(field2);

        button = new JButton("Login");
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == button) {
                    user = field1.getText();
                    pass = field2.getText();

                    if(user.equals(Connect.username) && pass.equals(Connect.password)) {
                        answer.setText("Logged in");
                    } else {
                        answer.setText("Bad login data try again");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

        answer = new JLabel("");
        panel.add(answer);

        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(500, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("Login");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connect.ConnectDB();
        new GuiLogin();
    }

    }
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Please post the schema for your table(s) and describe your exact problem.

Comment: Do you just need to find a record where one of the fields is equal to your parameter and retrieve a value of another field from this record? `SELECT username from Users WHERE password=<entered value>`?

Comment: Mhm, if i have 2 records in table, like i posted above, i want to be able to check if any of those is entered and if it is than process it and say logged in blah blah blah...

Comment: Concentrate just on the database part. What do you want to retrieve and based on what?

Comment: With query i need to check if ANY of records from Database are equal to user input. For example if there is record in database 
myUsername,myPassword. And user enters that than log he in.....
Hope you understand me now :)

Comment: See the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0c4ac/4) I created. Right now if there's no match it returns no rows (your ResultSet would be empty).

Comment: Use [`Prepared Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps) with parameters.

Comment: Yes that is great, you got it, But can i check inside query if for example in the fiddle you made if i replace password = GuiLogin.pass (which is entered inside GuiLogin.java which i posted above) How about that?

Comment: You need to learn how to pass parameters to a query (and avoid security problems).  I've provided a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to such tutorial.

Comment: All right, i will check it out thanks for your effort in trying to help beginner like me!!! Cheers!

Comment: **Do not store unhashed passwords!**. You should store a hashed and salted password, retrieve that by username and then hash the password from the user with the salt of the stored password. If the stored and the fresh hash are identical then the password is correct. And as to the rest of your question: please look at a JDBC tutorial on `PreparedStatement`, like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually he shouldn't retrieve the password at all. He should search for a row where the username and password match the user inputs, and just see if there was such a row. The password matching and hashing should be done entirely by the DBMS.

Comment: @EJP IMO it shouldn't, and most authentication solutions I know usually don't use the - generally weak - hashing functions of a database. And frankly it would even create a security risk as most databases have a tracing facility that can output queries and parameter values (the password included!). Keeping the password inside the app, retrieve the hash and applicable salt and then hash the password with the same salt seems to me to be safer.

Answer (score 0):

You should call ConnectDB into ActionPerformed method, because in your code data from database is gotten before GUI is loaded, instead data from DB should be loaded after user enters his name and password and clicks "Login" button.

Rewrite the GUI class like that:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GuiLogin extends JFrame {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField field1;
    private JPasswordField field2;
    private JLabel label1, label2, answer;

    static String user;
    static String pass;

    public GuiLogin() {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        panel = new JPanel();

        label1 = new JLabel("Username:");
        panel.add(label1);

        field1 = new JTextField("", 15);
        panel.add(field1);

        label2 = new JLabel("Password:");
        panel.add(label2);

        field2 = new JPasswordField("", 15);
        panel.add(field2);

        button = new JButton("Login");
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == button) {
                    user = field1.getText();
                    pass = field2.getText();

                    Connect.ConnectDB();

                    if (user.equals(Connect.username)
                            && pass.equals(Connect.password)) {
                        answer.setText("Logged in");
                    } else {
                        answer.setText("Bad login data try again");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

        answer = new JLabel("");
        panel.add(answer);

        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(500, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("Login");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuiLogin();
    }
}
```

Now SQL query that is commented will work. So use the query:

```
query = "SELECT admin,password FROM user WHERE admin = '" + GuiLogin.user + "' AND password = '" + GuiLogin.pass + "'";
```